# How do you use ASP.NET Cache object in a not ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I'd like to use System.Web.Caching.Cache object in my application, but this code throws a NullReferenceException.

```
Cache cache = new Cache();
cache["key"] = new object();
```

Any ideas ?

***Update***

HttpRuntime.Cache solve my problem but does somebody has a solution to use multiple instance of cache in my application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`HttpRuntime.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) static property; it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a solution to not use a level application cache ?

Comment: You mean to allow multiple instances of it in a single process? Not that I've found, no (although admittedly I haven't looked very hard as I only need one cache per process).

Comment: Yes it's what I meant. It would be better with multiple instance because with this singleton unit tests are not independant anymore.

Comment: What we do to get around that is stick the ASP.NET cache behind a custom ICache interface, and then during unit tests you can use a quick and dirty mock implementation.

Answer (score 2):

[Enterprise Library Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309502.aspx) might help you. It works fine for Windows applications as well as ASP.NET Applications.